# Is the word 'expensive' negative or neutral?

Tags: adjectives, exam-questions, connotations

I'm not a native speaker of English. I'm trying to teach English learners positive and negative words.

I found this word in students' textbook, which only gives me the choice between positive and negative. I doubt the correctness of the textbook. Is the word 'expensive' negative or neutral?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really depends on the context, and because of that, I think you would be best to say neutral. For example, here are three cases:

> Positive: My friend brought an expensive wine to the party for us to try.
>
> Neutral: The electric dryer was more expensive than the gas.
>
> Negative: I was shocked by how expensive hotel rooms were because of the convention.

I would say that *in general* most English speakers would say something being "expensive" is a bad thing, but actual usage is rarely that simple. Ultimately, the connotation depends on who is paying the "expensive" price.

Comment: All those uses are the same. One is  not more negative than the other. It is the surrounding context that is positive, neutral or negative.

Comment: @Lambie That is kind of the point.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it could be both. If you use the sentence

> That toy was way too expensive!

the connotation is negative.
If you use the sentence

> The blue boat is more expensive than the red one

it's not. So the answer depends on the sentence.

Comment: That second example is not one of a positive connotation; it can still go both ways.

Comment: That is very true.

Answer (score 0):

The literal meaning of expensive is that it costs a lot of money. It depends on your view if that is a negative or a neutral thing. It also depends on the reason why something is expensive. It is quite a philosophical question, I think.